# How to return multiple select queries from stored procedure to Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using Entity Model in my application(EF Designer from database). My stored procedure has 2 select queries. After going through so many articles i found that i had to manually change the complex type of the entity model(to achieve what i intend to. Or is there any other way?). I have changed it but when i access i am getting the result set of the first select query only. How to get result set of both the queries?

For Ex: This is my stored procedure.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Win_Test_Multiple_Result_Set_Entity]
as
begin 
select court_type,court_name from mst_courttype
select code,name from mst_bincom
end
```

This is my modified function import and complex type:

```
<FunctionImport Name="Win_Test_Multiple_Result_Set_Entity" >
            <ReturnType Type="Collection(vb_sql_rtcModel.Win_Test_Multiple_Result_Set_Entity_Result)"></ReturnType>
            <ReturnType Type="Collection(vb_sql_rtcModel.Win_Test_Multiple_Result_Set_Entity_Topic)"></ReturnType>
          </FunctionImport> 


<ComplexType Name="Win_Test_Multiple_Result_Set_Entity_Result">
          <Property Type="Byte" Name="court_type" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="court_name" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" />
        </ComplexType>
        <ComplexType Name="Win_Test_Multiple_Result_Set_Entity_Topic">
          <Property Type="Byte" Name="code" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="name" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" />
        </ComplexType>
```

And this is my Function Import Mapping:

```
<FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="Win_Test_Multiple_Result_Set_Entity" FunctionName="vb_sql_rtcModel.Store.Win_Test_Multiple_Result_Set_Entity">
            <ResultMapping>
              <ComplexTypeMapping TypeName="vb_sql_rtcModel.Win_Test_Multiple_Result_Set_Entity_Result">
                <ScalarProperty Name="court_type" ColumnName="court_type" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="court_name" ColumnName="court_name" />
              </ComplexTypeMapping>              
            </ResultMapping>
            <ResultMapping>
              <ComplexTypeMapping TypeName="vb_sql_rtcModel.Win_Test_Multiple_Result_Set_Entity_Topic">
                <ScalarProperty Name="code" ColumnName="court_type" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="name" ColumnName="court_name" />
              </ComplexTypeMapping>

            </ResultMapping>
          </FunctionImportMapping>
```

How i am accessing:

```
IList<Win_Test_Multiple_Result_Set_Entity_Result> obj = EntityObj.Win_Test_Multiple_Result_Set_Entity().ToList<Win_Test_Multiple_Result_Set_Entity_Result>();
```

Here i am the getting only the result set of first query i.e court_type and court_name. But i want the result set of both the queries. How to achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot do this with EF - if you really must return *multiple* result sets from a single stored procedure, there's no other way than to use basic, raw ADO.NET (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader`) to handle those multiple result sets.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj691402(v=vs.113).aspx